# ViewState in the ASP.NET, does it really go away?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, viewstate

I have read different topics, tutorials etc... Everywhere there is an information that `ASP.NET MVC` has an advantage for not using/containg a `ViewState` stuff.

Really?

So... How could it be (look at the screenshot)?

http://s18.postimg.org/rvgm2ypjt/Screenshot_568.png

As you can see in the screen it isn't a `WebForms` project.

I just added the next code in the one `View`:

http://ideone.com/iPkmdO

Why do I have a `Viewstate` in my `ASP.NET MVC` project?

Comment: That's odd. Which template did you use to create the MVC application?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları what do you mean by the word `template`? The version of ASP.NET MVC? It's the second version (ASP.NET MVC 2). If you want to know, how do I create project? Simply... Just choose `New ASP.NET MVC 2 application with tests` (it could be seen if the solution explorer).

Comment: There is a [template dialog](http://i1.asp.net/common/www-css/i/mvc3/image005a.png) before creating the project.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları before I have installed the ASP.NET MVC 4 for Visual Studio 2010 - I haven't such a dialogue, which you have showed. Only after I've installed a new install package, which add the MVC 4 to my VS, there has appeared such a dialogue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="MainForm" runat="server">
```

If you are using `runat="server"`, then you are *invoking* webforms; don't do that. This is MVC - you don't need that. Just change it to:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="MainForm">
```

Answer (score -1):

**It's because you are using aspx pages in MVC project.**  *(In the screenshot I can see ViewMaps.aspx)*

Aspx pages are webforms. Webforms have viewstate.

If use use the proper Controllers and Views, you will not see any viewstate. Just because the project is MVC doesn't mean that viewstate will not be present on aspx pages.

Also, people generally don't use aspx pages in MVC projects.

Comment: Wait... But I've created just new ASP.NET MVC 2 application with tests, I expanded the other pages of this project, look here: http://s11.postimg.org/wf5zocodf/image.png , I didn't even created them! They were built auto, when the new project was creating by Visual Studio.

Comment: Hmmm.. that's strange. And its a totally different question altogether. Hopefully now you are convinced that MVC doesn't have viewstate.

Comment: I have never worked with MVC 2. And its weird that MVC 2 has such template that creates aspx pages.

Comment: @GeloVolro Have you tried using a different template. Visual studio 2010/2012 will give you default templates that may be useful to you.

Comment: I kinda disagree with this answer; aspx was used as the **view engine** in MVC initially; that doesn't mean it is webforms. Simply, MVC re-used an existing engine for rendering the views. While razor might be tidier, the presence of aspx *by itself*  doesn't say "webforms", and shouldn't imply viewstate